# How to unhide a section using onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

On my home page, the login section is hidden from the users site when they load the page using

```
    $('#login').hide();
```

When the user clicks the login link at the top of the page, it fires this line of code

```
<a onlick="ShowLogin" href="#login">Login</a>
```

The above onclick calls this code, which I thought would then make the section visible

At the moment, on load the login section is not visible, but the onclick does not work, not sure what have I missed?

```
function ShowLogin() {
    $('.signup').hide();
    $('.lostdetails').hide();
    $('#login').show();
}
```

Login section

```
<section id="login">
>         <div class="container">
>             <div class="row">
>                 <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
>                     <h2>Login to get some kudosoo</h2>
>                     <hr class="star-primary">
>                 </div>
>                   ... </section>
```

Comment: It probably doesn't work because your attribute in the <a> tag says `onlick` not `onclick`

Comment: Also you don't call any function, you have to put `ShowLogin()` with the braces

Comment: Wow, some people are harsh marking this down, it maybe simple to some, but not others that are learning. Constructive feedback to how the question could be written better is more useful

Comment: Tip: Get a proper IDE, it should have warned you about the typo in onclick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You error is `ShowLogin` and `onlick`.

Change this,

```
<a onclick="ShowLogin" href="#login">Login</a>
```

To,

```
<a onclick="ShowLogin();" href="#login">Login</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href="#login"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.signup,.lostdetails').slideUp('slow',function(){$('#login').slideDown('slow');});//cool effect for you ;)
});
```

basically, you have your selector which is the anchor link, but I'm looking specifically for the anchor with `href="#login"`.

the `e` variable is the events variable. `e.preventDefault()` prevents the default browser event which with an anchor would move to the top of the elements `#login`.

then sliding both the unwanted elements up and using the `slideUp()` callback function to `slideDown()` the login element :)